# Flutter TextSpan Gesture detection function

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create a List of '''TextSpans'''.
If you press on a word this word should change.

For Example:

**This tree looks great** => onTapped 'Tree' the String should change to **This tree, looks great**.

If you press the button again the value should change to default value: **This tree looks great**.

Is there anyway to do it?

```
class Satz extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SatzState createState() => _SatzState();
}

class _SatzState extends State<Satz> {
  
  String stringValue= 'The tree looks great';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          body: Container(
                 child: ListView.builder(

                   itemCount: 1,
                   itemBuilder: (context, length,){
                    return RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                        children: createTextSpans(stringValue)));
                   }) )
          );}}
  List<TextSpan> createTextSpans(stringValue){
    final string = stringValue;
    final arrayStrings = string.split(" ");
    List<TextSpan> arrayOfTextSpan = [];
    for (int index = 0; index < arrayStrings.length; index++){
      final text = arrayStrings[index] + " ";
      final span = TextSpan(
        text: text,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = () {
          print(text);
        }
      );
      arrayOfTextSpan.add(span);
    }
    return arrayOfTextSpan;
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you want every word to behave like this, not just Tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could give you an idea. Try something like this,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Satz(),
  ));
}

class Satz extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SatzState createState() => _SatzState();
}

class _SatzState extends State<Satz> {
  String stringValue = 'The tree looks great';
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: Container(
          child: ListView(
        children: [
          RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              children: stringValue.split(' ').asMap().entries.map((entry) {
                String text = entry.value;
                int index = entry.key;
                return TextSpan(
                  text: text + " ",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
                  recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () {
                      List<String> correctedValue = stringValue.replaceAll(',','').split(' ');
                      print(correctedValue[index]);
                      if(!text.contains(',')){
                        correctedValue[index] += ',';                      
                      }
                      setState(
                        () {
                          stringValue = correctedValue.join(' ');
                        },
                      );
                    },
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that it does not work for a other sentence. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Can you say what are those sentences ad how it should behave?

Comment: The whole idea of the App is that the user should learn where a comma in a sentence should be. Therefore I have a lot of different sentences. This Page should take one sentenence and  every word pressable. This is why I'm using the TextSpan Widget. If the user click on the word the word should change to a word with a comma. If the user click on the word a second time the comma should disapear.

Comment: I'm so thankful!!!!!! One Problem still exist. In some sentences the user has to add 2 or more commas. In this version the user can just add one comma. I don't know how to write the code for it , but comma should just disappear when the same word pressed

Comment: Then, you need to count the number of commas before doing this operation.

Comment: Do you mean it this way:    Every sentence has to have a value for how many commas ought to be in the sentence.